# Get type of generic functions first argument

Tags: typescript, react-navigation

This type is given

```
declare type NavigationHelpersCommon<ParamList extends ParamListBase> = {
    /**
     * Navigate to a route in current navigation tree.
     *
     * @param name Name of the route to navigate to.
     * @param [params] Params object for the route.
     */
    navigate<RouteName extends keyof ParamList>(...args: undefined extends ParamList[RouteName] ? [screen: RouteName] | [screen: RouteName, params: ParamList[RouteName]] : [screen: RouteName, params: ParamList[RouteName]]): void;
}
```

And I want to create a function that has the same first argument signature like the `navigate` generic function.

```
type ScreenName = Parameters<typeof navigationRef.navigate>[0]

function pickAsync<T extends ScreenName>(screen: T, eventName: string) {
  navigate(screen) // typings are OK
}

// Calling my function gives TS error about incompatible type for first argument
pickAsync("Login", "LOGIN")
```

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ key: string; params?:
{ screen?: undefined; params?: undefined; initial?: undefined; path?: string | undefined;
 state: Readonly<{ key: string; index: number; routeNames: string[]; history?: unknown[] 
| undefined; routes: NavigationRoute<...>[]; type: string; stale: false; }> | 
PartialState<...> | undefined; } | .....'.ts(2345)
```

How would I have to type the first argument for my function to match the one from the `navigate` function?

Comment: Please try to make your code a minimal reproduction such that anyone could copy your code and run it while getting the same results.  I don't know where the `ParamListBase` type, `navigatorRef` constant, or `navigate` function that is called are coming from.

Comment: they are from react-navigation package https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation